# Vue overlay navigation

Tags: vue.js

I created this Vue app with side overlay nav and I am trying to recreate it again using a better approach, but since I am new to Vue I do not how. Is there a better way to do this without using javascript DOM to select the element by ID and set it width, using just Vue? I know that there is a better way to do this this with Vue.

```js
var openNav = () => {
  document.getElementById('myNav').style.width = '50%'
}
var closeNav = () => {
  document.getElementById('myNav').style.width = '0%'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    openOverlay () {
      openNav()
    },
    closeOverlay () {
      closeNav()
    }
  },
})

$(function () {
  openNav()
  closeNav()
})
```

```css
.navbar-left {
    @include inputStyle(2em)
  }

  .navbar-icon {
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }

  .navbar-icon::before {
    content: '\F0C9';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  .overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  .overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  .overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="app">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center navbar-left">
        <button type="button"
                @click="openOverlay"
                class="navbar-toggler navbar-icon"
                data-toggle="collapse" />
        
      </div>
      <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
           class="closebtn" @click="closeOverlay">&times;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a data property:

```
data () {
  return { 
    open: false
  }
}
```

now just use 1 function:

```
methods: {
  toggleOverlay() {
    this.open = !this.open
  }
}
```

now just use the `open` property to determine when the width should be set. for simplicity, we'll do it inline:

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" :style="{ width: open ? '50%': '0' }">
```

Now change both your click handlers to reference `toggleOverlay`:

```
@click="toggleOverlay"
```